# Flutter FileParse Delete Failed because ObjectId is null

Tags: parse-platform

i upload my files to a self-hosted parse server using i am using `parse-server-fs-adapter`
here is my code to upload the files

```
if (files != null) {
  var filesList = <ParseFile>[];
  for (var file in files!) {
    var parseFile = ParseFile(File(file.path!));
    var fileUploadResponse = await parseFile.save();
    if (fileUploadResponse.success) {
      filesList.add(fileUploadResponse.result as ParseFile);
    }
  }
}
obj.set('files', filesList);
```

However, when i try to delete i get an exception because ObjectId is null. How can i delete a file? , is there a possibility to delete the actual file from the server? thank you very much

file.delete() returns an exception objectId is null.